# How to make a scene a default start page in Corona SDK

Tags: lua, coronasdk

So I have 2 pages. `view1` and `view2`. And what I have is my `main.lua` as well as `view1.lua` and `view2.lua`.

And in my `main.lua` I have this:

```
-- show default status bar (iOS)
display.setStatusBar( display.HiddenStatusBar )
```

And that is it, this is because I recently added buttons instead of a tab bar for my page navigation. So on `view1` I have:

```
local playbtn = widget.newButton{
    left = 10,
    top = 600,
    defaultFile = "icon2.png",
    overFile = "icon2-down.png",
    onPress = onplaybtn
}

function onplaybtn( event )
    composer.gotoScene( "view2" )
end
```

So this button on the first page will navigate to the second page and on the second page I have:

```
local exitbtn = widget.newButton{
    left = 1096,
    top = 5,
    defaultFile = "icon1.png",
    overFile = "icon1-down.png",
    onPress = onexitbtn,
}

function onexitbtn( event )
    composer.gotoScene( "view1" )
end
```

So this is my second button. And basically I have a button on `view1` to navigate to `view2`. And then on `view2` I have a button that will navigate to `view1` so you can go between scenes. However, how would I make `view1` the default page when starting the app because obviously there is nothing in `main.lua` so it is just a black screen. Thanks

(Ask if you need more information because I am still new to Corona SDK and am not sure if you would need extra things).

--Edit

When I had my tab along the bottom, in my `main.lua` I had something at the bottom which was `onFirstView()` and apparently that set `view1` to the default page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the bottom of your main call

```
composer.gotoScene( "view1" )
```

And remember to include the composer in the top of your main aswell

```
local composer = require( "composer" )
```